# pass three parms on an ajax call with jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am trying to pass 4 parms on an ajax call with jquery.
Only the first parm works. The other thee do not.

```
var share_nid = $('.share_class').attr('share_nid');
            var share_type = $('.share_class').attr('share_type');
            var share_message = $('.share_class').attr('share_message');

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/sites/default/themes/ajax/ajax_share_content.php",
                data: {uid: <?php echo $user->uid ?>,
                      nid: share_nid,
                      type: share_type,
                      message: share_message}
                success: (function( msg ) {
                    alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
                })

or maybe like this...

$.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/sites/default/themes/ajax/ajax_share_content.php",
                data: {"uid=<?php echo $user->uid ?>&nid="+share_nid+"&type="share_type"&message="share_message,
                success: (function( msg ) {
                    alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
                })

        });
```

.
.
.
.
.
.

**edit**
 This is what worked for me... Is this "safe" from injection. Is using JSON better?

```
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/sites/default/themes/ajax/ajax_share_content.php",
            data: "uid=<?php echo $user->uid ?>&nid="+share_nid+"&type="+share_type+"&message="+share_message,
            success: (function( msg ) {
                alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
            }),

    });
```

Comment: HTML does not have attributes named `share_nid` or anything else `share_`-like. You shouldn't invent custom attributes - there are `data-` attributes for it. You could e.g. do `data-share-nid="something"` and then access it in jQuery via `.data('shareNid')`

Comment: Passing a string instead of an object is a bad solution. It should work with the object you have!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code you posted shouldn't work at all - it contains a syntax error: After `share_message}` you need a `,`. Besides that, there's no reason to enclose the success function in `()`.

By the way, using firebug you can easily find out what's actually sent (nothing should be sent since the code of the function call is erroneous) and where an error occurs (actually, the latter can be done without FB by simply opening the error console).

Comment: Thanks!!!!! Syntax fixed...I am having trouble with js variable substitution ...  {uid: <?php echo $user->uid ?>,
                      nid: share_nid,
                      type: share_type,
                      message: share_message}

Comment: from firebug: uid=3&nid=share_nid&type=share_type&message=share_message